# Помогите составить запрос выборки SQL со сложной сортировкой

Tags: mysql, sql

Помогите составить запрос выборки SQL со сложной сортировкой

Вот описание таблиц (моделей):

```
class SKU():
    pass

class EntitySKU():
    sku = ForeignKey(SKU)
    attribute = ForeignKey(Attribute)
    attributevalue = ForeignKey(AttributeValue)

class AttributeValue():
    value = CharField("Значение")
    my_order = IntegerField(default=0)

class Attribute():
    title = models.CharField("Название", max_length=255)
    my_order = IntegerField(default=0)
```

Нужно получить SKU, отсортированные по Attribute.my_order и AttributeValue.my_order, но каскадом (согласно приоритету).

Вот пример запроса обычного:

```
SELECT `product_sku`.`id`, `product_attribute`.`title`, `product_attributevalue`.`value`,
`product_attribute`.`my_order` AS attribute_order,
`product_attributevalue`.`my_order` AS attributevalue_order
FROM `product_sku` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `product__entity_sku` ON (`product_sku`.`id` = `product__entity_sku`.`sku_id`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `product_attribute` ON (`product__entity_sku`.`attribute_id` = `product_attribute`.`id`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `product_attributevalue` ON (`product__entity_sku`.`value_id` = `product_attributevalue`.`id`) 
WHERE `product_sku`.`product_id` = 1 
ORDER BY `product_attribute`.`my_order` ASC, `product_attributevalue`.`my_order` ASC
```

И вот его результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**А нужно ID в следующем порядке и без дублей:
2, 303, 304, 1, 4, 3**

То есть:

Чёрный S, Белый XXS ..., Красный ...

**Пример реализации предложенный в комментариях (сработал):**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ничего не понятно. почему белый должен быть первым, если черный с меньшим val_order. Откуда в выборке Черный XXS, если в примере данных нет такого варианта. но если все таки указанный жирным шрифтом порядок, то сгруппировать все по id и отсортировать по чему то вроде `sum(pow(10, 10-attribute_order)*attributevalue_order)`

Comment: Извиняюсь, ошибка в последнем списке, сначала чёрные со всеми размерами, потом белые и так далее... Ваш вариант на удивление сработал ))

Comment: Только вот решение не кажется самым оптимальным, так как то же значение attribute_order может быть намного больше, что приведёт к ошибке, если оно вдруг окажется отрицательным

Comment: ну какие данные дали, такую формулу и придумал. в любом случае все сводится к подбору подходящей формулы для конкретной ситуации. Можно еще попробовать собрать подходящую для сортировки строку с помощью group_concat, из value отсортированных по attr_order, возможно применив lpad до какого то кол-ва знаков. И да, если по цифрам полный разнобой, то можно с помощью переменных заранее пронумеровать строки в нужном порядке, что бы получить строго и гарантированно 1,2,3, а потом уже к этому числу применять sum с формулами